# (C# .NET 5 REST API) Input is invalid while using converters to add polymorphism

Tags: c#, .net, api, polymorphism, odata

I am trying to use polymorphism in my REST API using converters. I walked through this tutorial: https://newbedev.com/deserialising-json-to-derived-types-in-asp-net-web-api and adjusted it to my own base class and derived types.

The request I am sending is this:

```
{
  "createdBy": "string",
  "createdAt": "2021-08-23T14:42:21.500Z",
  "modifiedBy": "string",
  "modifiedAt": "2021-08-23T14:42:21.500Z",
  "id": 0,
  "points": 0,
  "text": "test",
  "quizId": 4,
  "quizOptions": [
  ]
}
```

It works when I remove the 'text' attribute, but ofcourse I get an interal server error, because it can't be parsed to neither 'ImageOptionDto' or 'TextOptionDto'.

My converter:

```
public class QuizOptionJsonConverter : JsonCreationConverter<QuizOptionDto>
{
    protected override QuizOptionDto Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject)
    {
        if (jObject == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("jObject");

        if (jObject["text"] != null)
        {
            return jObject.ToObject<TextOptionDto>();
        }
        else if (jObject["imageUrl"] != null)
        {
            return jObject.ToObject<ImageOptionDto>();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

My base class:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(QuizOptionJsonConverter))]
public class QuizOptionDto : IdentifierBaseModelDto
{
    public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }
    public int QuizQuestionId { get; set; }
    public QuizQuestionDto QuizQuestion { get; set; }
}
```

My derived classes:

```
public class TextOptionDto : QuizOptionDto
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public class ImageOptionDto : QuizOptionDto
{
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

After some research I also added this to my Startup.cs

```
options.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new QuizQuestionJsonConverter());
options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new QuizOptionJsonConverter());
```

My problem exactly is that when I make an api call with my derived attribute for example: 'text' it return "Input is invalid" e.g. 400). I tried to suppress model state validation, but then the parameter in my post method was just "null". So apparently, something is going very wrong here.

I debugged the code and concluded that my code doesn't come past the `CanConvert` method. I checked the type of the 'objectType (parameter from the method)' and it says:

[image]

I would expect 'TextOptionDto' to be the type here instead of 'AnnotatedProblemDetails'. I know what is going on here, but I don't know how to fix it.

The error:

```
{
  "$type": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.ValidationProblemDetailsConverter+AnnotatedValidationProblemDetails, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson",
  "errors": {
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib],[System.String[], System.Private.CoreLib]], System.Private.CoreLib",
    "": {
      "$type": "System.String[], System.Private.CoreLib",
      "$values": [
        "The input was not valid."
      ]
    }
  },
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-742ca70c9de2454bac8f94422bc49a2b-bd270ab858be3d43-00"
}
```

Can you guys help me?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

After some research I found the problem. It appears to have something to do with my EDM from OData. When I remove this part:

```
public static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EnableLowerCamelCase();
        
        // The name in the string must be the same as the controller classname e.g. Users
        builder.EntitySet<ProductDto>("Products");
        builder.EntitySet<CategoryDto>("Categories");
        builder.EntitySet<TextBlockDto>("TextBlocks");
        builder.EntitySet<MediaDto>("Media");
        builder.EntitySet<QuizDto>("Quizzes");
        builder.EntitySet<QuizResultDto>("QuizResults");
        builder.EntitySet<QuizQuestionDto>("QuizQuestions"); <---
        builder.EntitySet<UserDto>("Users");

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

It works perfectly fine, but ofcourse this controller won't be using OData if I do that.

Any suggestions on how to build my model, so that it allows inheritance?

Comment: Text may be a keyword. Try renaming it and see if it accepts it.

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work, because the other derived type with 'imageUrl' results in a 400 aswell.